# Hyperledger fabric front end creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to create the front end application for Hyperledger fabric.As the hyperledger composer is been depricated.What methodology is been used to create a front end.

Comment: Probably a better question to post to the Fabric mailing list:  https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric provides a good solution to view what is happening inside the blockchain.
It is called Fabric Explorer: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

Anyways, your question was not so clear so I am not sure this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a front end to your hyperledger fabric application then you are free to use whatever frameworks and libraries you want. You could for example create a Rest Server in node.js using express or loopback that utilises the hyperledger fabric node sdk to interact with your smart contract. From there you could develop a front end using a framework such as react or angular which interfaces to your rest server. This is just one approach there are lots of alternative approaches.

However I suspect what you want is something that just does all this for you and unfortunately I don't know of any tools that will do all this for you from an already implemented smart contract. There are probably tools that can generate the basics for you and then you would need to customise these generated implementations to your smart contract.